# React Native iOS: Real-Time Audio Frequency

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to get the frequency from an audio input in real time on iOS 9.3. I can get an audio file using the [`react-native-audio`](https://github.com/jsierles/react-native-audio) package.

I am currently getting the frequency from the audio file generated by `react-native-audio` using the [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API). This is done by passing the generated file into a `WebView`.

For this to be real time, will it have to be written in Objective-C or Swift, if so are there any packages/libraries built in those languages to get the frequency from the microphone input?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar problem right now ...

Comment: We ended up building this functionality in Swift.